# Booting Problem : can't request region for resource

Tags: boot, 16.04, live-usb

I'm quite new at this because I've been using windows and now I'm stuck not knowing what to do. I created a bootable USB stick with Rufus, changed the boot options and started to boot Ubuntu. It shows the grub menu and the first 2 choices are install or try without installing. When I select either on of those 2, it starts booting but then hangs in the loading screen. I pressed F2 and I get the error:

> can't request region for resource

I have tried every possible combination of BIOS settings, Rufus settings and some of the solutions that I found online but nothing works. I even formatted Windows 10 and still nothing. All drivers are up to date. I just run out of ideas, need help.

Comment: You appear to be affected by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/intel/+bug/1596469)

Comment: Voting to reopen it because it's in top search results and the connected question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was a mixture of both of those threads. By getting started Ubuntu with the `nomodeset` I was able to install both Ubuntu and the drivers needed (I have 2 graphics cards in my laptop and apparently that causes the problem) and now everything runs smoothly.

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted if you are still around